# Can't log in as registered user in MongooseIM with MySQL ODBC

Tags: mysql, erlang, odbc, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I've spent all day trying to figure out how to properly set up MongooseIM to use ODBC with MySQL.

Here's my ejabberd.conf: http://pastebin.com/Lyptf4Jm

I can register a user with the command `mongooseimctl register user domain.example.com password`
And I can see that the password is indeed correct in the users table (though stored in plaintext, which I want to change if possible) but I can't connect from Pidgin. I get "Not Authorized".

This is only one in a list of issues I'm having with MongooseIM at the moment, but it's the most important one right now. Can anyone help or at least point me in the direction of a document detailing what needs to be done to set up MongooseIM to properly work with MySQL?

Comment: I checked it - you've found a bug. Could you post an issue at https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM?

Comment: Moreover, Pidgin must be configured not to use Cyrus SASL to support SCRAM-SHA-1 (see https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/FullChangeLog). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I will post an issue for it. Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/301) is the issue, and [here](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/pull/320) is the fix.  The fix was included in MongooseIM 1.5.0.